# DRm support for html5 player

Tags: drm

I am trying to run angular js application on mobile device with html5 player for video playback.

I would like to know whether html5 supports drm by default  or is there a way to support drm in html5.

Regards,
Raj Dugar

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 supports DRM through the Encrypted Media Extensions (EME) mechanism, which in turn relies on the Media Source Extensions (MSE) mechanism.

Essentially, the DRM system provides a Content Decryption Module (CDM) which is built into or added to the browser and which is accessed by the HTML5/Javascript via EME to decrypt and possibly to playback encrypted media.

Not all browser support all CDMs - in general Chrome supports Widevine CDM, MS Edge supports Playready CDM and Safari supports FairPlay CDM. Firefox supports Adobe Primetime and Widevine CDM, although the momentum seems to be with the latter.

You can read more about EME here:

- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/

and the spec is here:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-encrypted-media-20160705/

Comment: is it still a nightmare to setup DRM in 2018 front 2 back?